# Power BI Pivot Colums to Rows

Tags: reporting, powerbi

New to Power BI and attempting to pivot sub header to row. Currently I have this...

[image]

I need the "actual" and "definite" columns to display as rows like this...

[image]

I've tried using the matrix visualization to adjust columns, rows, and values, but no luck so far. This is what I have that produces the first matrix above...

[image]

This is the closest I've found to an answer

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Value-Headers/m-p/65124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reshape the data in the Edit Queries window.  I would select the **actual** and **definite** columns, and choose Unpivot Columns.

Back on the Matrix, you can then use the generated **Attribute** field (or whatever you rename that to) as nested Rows under your **Hotels** field, and the generated **Value** field as Values.